# Как создать класс,который будет создавать экземпляр объекта другого класса и вызывать его методы

Tags: java

Как создать класс,который будет создавать экземпляр объекта другого класса и вызывать его методы.
Заранее спасибо за ответ на глупый вопрос!

Comment: А если в моем новом классе мне не нужен метод main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Start{

public static void main(String[] args){

 Cat cat; //переменная для хранения экземпляра

 cat = new Cat(); //сам экземпляр класса Cat мы поместили в переменную

 cat.method1(); //вызов метода 

 }

}

class Cat{

 void method1()
 {
  System.out.println("I am Cat!");
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Cat { //метод этого класса будем вызывать в классе CatWoman
         public void meow() {
              System.out.println("meow");
         }
    }

    class CatWoman {
         private Cat cat; // переменная для хранения экземпляра

         public CatWoman() { // конструктор для инициализации (можно опустить)
              this.cat = new Cat();
         }

         public void meow() { // вызываем метод экземпляра
              cat.meow();
         }
    }

class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args){
          CatWoman catWoman = new CatWoman();
          catWoman.meow();
     }
}
```